# Change last logon for user(s) in Active Directory

Tags: active-directory, users

Is there any way to artificially change the "lastLogon" and/or "lastLogonTimestamp" for a user?

I have a script that disables and/or deletes old users and I want to make sure it is getting the dates correctly with test users before I put it into production.

I have tried using an LDAP tool, but I am seemingly not allowed to alter that user property - I get the error "Unwilling to perform".

All suggestions are welcome.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can accomplish that using adsi edit, it's a very powerful tool, so be careful.

- start->run->"adsiedit.msc"

  if you get "command not found" [this](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc773354%28WS.10%29.aspx#BKMK_InstallingADSIEdit) should help
- browse to the user
- right click, properties
- there you are :)

Answer (score 2):

There is also a sysinternals app called ADExplorer that you might want to check out.

Download here - http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb963907.aspx

Once you connect to your domain, you can browse down to the user and see the specific attributes.  Then right click and Modify the selected attribute.

Answer (score -1):

Note that **lastLogonTimestamp** is not replicated - each DC holds its own value.  To get a true picture of a person's last logon, you'll need to gather the value from each DC and determine which is the latest.

Comment: The **lastLogonTimestamp** *is* replicated, [perhaps not at the frequency one might expect](http://blogs.technet.com/b/askds/archive/2009/04/15/the-lastlogontimestamp-attribute-what-it-was-designed-for-and-how-it-works.aspx), it's the **lastLogon** [attribute that is not replicated](http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2010/01/27/dandelions-vcr-clocks-and-last-logon-times-these-are-a-few-of-our-least-favorite-things.aspx). I think your answer may have been better suited as a comment.

Comment: OK, not reliably replicated. You can't make account status changes based on one DC's value.  Been there.  Plus, you need to account for occasions when a DC will randomly return a NULL.  Haven't got to the bottom of this one yet (Win2k3 SP2 R2).

Comment: There is only one domain controller, so in this case I will be "safe" :)